# (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Tags: linux, bash

I am new to bash and linux and can't understand why do i have this error ((standard_in) 1: syntax error) in my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
file_data=$(<merge.bmp)
counter=0
file_size=$(stat -c%s "merge.bmp")
touch file1.bmp
touch file2.bmp
while [ $counter -lt 10 ]; do
    if [ `echo "$counter % 2" | bc` -eq 0 ]; then
            var=`xxd -p -l1 -s $counter merge.bmp`
            hex_var=$(echo "obase=16; $var" | bc) 
    else
            var=`xxd -p -l1 -s $counter merge.bmp`
            hex_var=$(echo "obase=16;$var" | bc)
    fi
    let counter=counter+1
done
echo "DONE!"
```

Comment: Do you have proper line endings in your file? I mean LF and not CRLF?
Additionally, there are quite few elements in your script that do not make much sense, e.g. `file_data` and `hex_var` are not used. Try running it via [`ShellCheck`](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

That's the error coming out of the tool `bc` you had used for arithmetic evaluation. I suspect the variable assignment, `$var` leading to `echo "obase=16; $var" | bc` has a malformed/empty value which `bc` did not like.

If you are using the `bash` shell, you could very well use its over arithmetic evaluation using the `$((..))` construct as

```
for (( counter=0; counter<10; counter++ )); do
    if (( counter % 2 == 0 )); then
        var=$(xxd -p -l1 -s "$counter" merge.bmp)
        printf -v hex_var '%x' "$var"
    fi
done
```

The `%x` applies the necessary decimal to hex conversion needed. Moreover you are doing the same action in both `if` and `else` clause. Also remove the outdated back-ticks syntax for command substitution, rather use `$(..)`.

Comment: Testing if `counter` is even is unnecessary; just use `counter+=2` to skip odd numbers in the iteration.

Comment: @chepner : Yup true. Added it because OP had an else clause explicitly added. Thought he could fix the duplicate and reuse it.