# (standard_in 1: syntax error) if script run in a cronjob

Tags: bash, sh

I have this script to auto-resize a volume trough an API (Hetzner provider).
While this script works very well if I run it manually (`bash /opt/tools/volume_size.sh`), while in a cronjob:

```
*/20 * * * * /usr/bin/bash /opt/tools/volume_size.sh
```

it outputs this error:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

As one can see, the error is not very helpful as no line is specified. The script is also very valid accordingly to shelcheck.

Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check available space
AVAILABLE=$(/usr/bin/df -h | /usr/bin/grep encrypted | /usr/bin/awk '{print $4}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/G//g')

# If available space on volume is less than 100Gb
if (( $(/usr/bin/echo "$AVAILABLE < 100" | /usr/bin/bc -l) )); then

  # Check the volume size with Hetzner API
  VOLSIZE=$(/usr/bin/curl -s \
                -H "Authorization: Bearer $HETZNER_TOKEN" \
                'https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/volumes/123456' | \
                /usr/bin/grep size | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/,//g')

  # New volume size will be actual size + 50Gb
  NEWSIZE=$(( "$VOLSIZE" + 50 ))

  # Resize the Hetzner volume trough the API
  /usr/bin/curl -s \
        -X POST \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $HETZNER_TOKEN" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d "{\"size\":\"$NEWSIZE\"}" \
        'https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/volumes/14746432/actions/resize'

  /usr/bin/sleep 5

  # Check the volume size with Hetzner API after resizing
  NEWVOLSIZE=$(/usr/bin/curl -s \
                -H "Authorization: Bearer $HETZNER_TOKEN" \
                'https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/volumes/123456' | \
                /usr/bin/grep size | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/,//g')

  # If volume size after resizing is greater than before resizing
  # Resizing was successful, proceed
  if (( $(/usr/bin/echo "$NEWVOLSIZE > $VOLSIZE" | /usr/bin/bc -l) )); then

    # Resize the local ZFS pool
    /usr/sbin/zpool online -e datapool sdb

    # Check the pool size after resizing
    NEWAVAILABLE=$(df -h | /usr/bin/grep encrypted | /usr/bin/awk '{print $4}' | /usr/bin/sed 's/G//g')

    # If pool available space is greater than 100Gb
    # Resizing was successful
    if (( $(/usr/bin/echo "$NEWAVAILABLE > 100" | /usr/bin/bc -l) )); then
      /usr/bin/echo "ZFS Volume has been automatically resized from $VOLSIZE GB to $NEWSIZE GB. Current available space is $NEWAVAILABLE GB." | \
      /usr/bin/mail -s "[INFO] ZFS Volume has been auto-resized!" root
      exit 0
    else
      # Resizing failed...
      /usr/bin/echo "Please manually check your ZFS Volume as the available space is actually $NEWAVAILABLE GB." | \
      /usr/bin/mail -s "[WARNING] ZFS Volume can't be auto-resized!" root
      exit 1
    fi

  fi

fi

exit 0
```

If I run the script with no resizing needed (+100Gb available), it outputs:

```
# bash -x volume_size.sh
++ /usr/bin/df -h
++ /usr/bin/sed s/G//g
++ /usr/bin/awk '{print $4}'
++ /usr/bin/grep encrypted
+ AVAILABLE=140
++ /usr/bin/echo '140 < 100'
++ /usr/bin/bc -l
+ ((  0  ))
+ exit 0
```

Please note error only outputs if resize is needed (so, after the 1st `if` condition, line 7).

Comment: Try changing `df` by `/bin/df` just in PATH problem case. Or whereever it is  (use `which df` to know where it is in your system)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that cron is using bash to execute the script and not, say, sh?

Comment: Show your cronjob.

Comment: You would get better diagnostics if you would execute the script by `bash -x script.sh`.

Comment: When I [google that error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=%28standard_in%29+1%3A+syntax+error) there's lots of hits - have you read some of them to see if they answer your question? [The answer to the 2nd hit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48238833/1745001) suggests the call to `bc` - maybe take a look at that?

Comment: My cron line is `*/20 * * * * /usr/bin/bash /opt/tools/volume_size.sh`

Comment: Just set PATH, instead of `/usr/bin` everywhere.. `Please note error only outputs if resize is needed` So show `set -x` output when resize is needed... Please check your script with shellcheck. Anyway, most probably `NEWAVAILABLE=$( this here )` is wrong.

Comment: I know about `$PATH`, but this isn't an issue in any way. There is no difference between `$AVAILABLE` and `$NEWAVAILABLE`, (besides the `/usr/bin` missing on `df`) what could be wrong here?

Comment: If I type something rare like this: `$ echo "a$47 < 1t00" | bc -l`I am getting the same error too:
`(standard_in) 1: syntax error` so I suggest you to review what params are you passing to `bc` command in every case and set breakpoints in your code to know which `bc -l` is getting them wrong.

Comment: I fully get you points, may be a problem with `bc`, I'll further investigate it; what I can't understand is, why (when space needs to be resized) it outputs that error every 20mns (cron times) and I just need to run it manually once to get the script executed...correctly. Without any changes to it!

Comment: You'll know when you set that breakpoints in the `bc` calls.  I mean, there are 3 `bc` calls. If you put an `exit` after the first `bc` and execute the cron job, and you are not getting the error, then do the same for the second and later for the last one.  When you have found which one causes the error then you can debug it better using ECHOs or something about the values used and investigate further.

Comment: Well, I'll try another approach; I've used bc to avoid bad calculation with non-integers. I've modified code to be like this instead:

```# Check available space
AVAILABLE=$(df -B M /datapool | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/M//g')

# If available space on volume is less than 100Gb
if (( "$AVAILABLE < 100000" )); then```

and other occurrences too, to avoid using `bc`. I'll see if this helps and report back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my 100% working version. Globally, i'm now checking for Megabytes instead of Gigabytes, and avoid using `bc`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check available space
AVAILABLE=$(df -B M /datapool | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/M//g')

# If available space on volume is less than 100Gb
if (( "$AVAILABLE" < 100000 )); then

  TOKEN="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  # Check the volume size with Hetzner API
  VOLSIZE=$(curl -s \
                 -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
                 'https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/volumes/1474' | \
                 grep size | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/,//g')

  # New volume size will be actual size + 50Gb
  NEWSIZE=$(( "$VOLSIZE" + 50 ))

  # Resize the Hetzner volume trough the API
  curl -s \
       -X POST \
       -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       -d "{\"size\":\"$NEWSIZE\"}" \
       'https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/volumes/1474/actions/resize'

  RESIZED=$(curl -s \
                 -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
                 'https://api.hetzner.cloud/v1/volumes/1474' | \
                 grep size | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/,//g')

  if (( "$RESIZED" > "$VOLSIZE" )); then

    # Resize the local ZFS pool
    /usr/sbin/zpool online -e datapool sdb

    # Check the pool size after resizing
    NEWAVAILABLE=$(df -B M /datapool | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/M//g')

    # If pool available space is greater than 100Gb
    # Resizing was successful
    if (( "$NEWAVAILABLE" > "$AVAILABLE" )); then
      echo "NFS Volume has been automatically resized from $VOLSIZE GB to $NEWSIZE GB. Current available space is $NEWAVAILABLE GB." | \
      mail -s "[INFO] NFS Volume has been auto-resized!" root
      exit 0
    else
      # Resizing failed...
      echo "Please manually check your NFS Volume as the available space is actually $NEWAVAILABLE GB." | \
      mail -s "[WARNING] NFS Volume needs manual intervention!" root
      exit 1
    fi

  fi

fi

exit 0
```